# How can I write a program that counts the amount of numbers in a sentence?

Tags: c#, numbers

I am trying to write a code in C# that counts how many numbers are there in a sentence. So if the number is made up of more than a digit it should be counted as one number.
For example: 2021 is one number not 4 numbers

This problem is caused by the method 'Char.IsDigit'

I wrote a code but the only problem in my algorithms is that if a word starts with a number it will be counted as a number.
For example: **1big** will be counted as a number, but it shouldn't.

So how can I solve this problem?

My code might be a trivial code, so if there are better solutions I would be happy if you show me.

```
using System;

namespace Textanalyse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I count how many numbers are there in a text.");
            string text = "Hallo to the 1 that broke all my 12345 bones in my 2 legs, 2 hands and 20 fingers without touching my skull that has an IQ100 brain but 1big bone";
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {countTheNumbers(text)} in the sentence above");


            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static int countTheNumbers(string s)
        {

            int sum = 0;
            string[] everyWord = s.Split(" ");
            bool x;
            for (int i = 0; i < everyWord.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The {i + 1}. String is \"{everyWord[i]}\" and it contains ({everyWord[i].Length}) digits.");
                for (int j = 0; j < everyWord[i].Length; j++)
                {

                    x = char.IsDigit(everyWord[i], j);
                    Console.WriteLine(x);

                    if (x == false)
                        break;
                    else
                    {

                        sum = sum + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine($"\"{everyWord[i]}\" is a number");
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think logically step by step. First you want to check all the words... Okay so split by words. Then you want to check if the word is a number... Okay check if all character of that word is a digit.

Comment: Rather than the criteria of your algorithm being "if a word starts with a number", you need to change that to be "if *every character* in a word is a number"

Comment: `int count = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b[0-9]+\b").Count;`

Comment: @zaggler - "So if the number is made up of more than a digit it should be counted as one number. For example: 2021 is one number not 4 numbers"

Comment: @CodeStranger read too quick, ready for the weekend :)

Comment: `text.Split(" ").Select(s=>s.All(char.IsDigit)).Count(c=>c)`

Comment: @DanielMann You should try your code before adding as a comment. `Split` does not accept a string as parameter

Comment: I think the regular expression should do the trick, unless you want to solve it logically using the function Int.TryParse function provided in C#. Have a read.

Comment: @Franck Works just fine in .NET 5. The question didn't specify a framework or language version. In fact, the MVCE code provided by the original poster uses the same `Split` overload.

Comment: @Franck you are correct and I started doing that but I faced a problem in counting the amount of numbers in the string because every number in the string would return a true and every time a true is returned the sum/count will be added with one 

Those are the numbers in my example that should be counted: {1 ,12345, 2, 2, 20}
So the answer at the end should be 5 but instead of that i got 10 because 12345 got counted 5 times and 20 got counted 2 times, so I couldn't find a better solution so I used a trivial solution by putting a break in the if statement so only the first digit got checked

Comment: @DanielMann thank you for your answer. Yes I use .NET 5. Could u tell me, what does this code do and how it works?  .Select(s=>s.All(char.IsDigit)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thank u everyone for everything I really learned a lot from you

I found another idea that would work with my prof. thanks

```
using System;

namespace Textanalyse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I count how many numbers are there in a string.\nPlease enter a text: ");
            string satz = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {ZaehleZahlen(satz)} numbers in this sentence! ");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static int ZaehleZahlen(string s)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            string[] jedesWort = s.Split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < jedesWort.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < jedesWort[i].Length; j++)
                {               
                    bool x;
                    x = char.IsDigit(jedesWort[i], j);
                    if (x == false)
                        break;
                    else if (x == true)
                    {
                        if (j != jedesWort[i].Length-1) continue;
                        else
                        {
                            sum = sum + 1;
                            Console.WriteLine($"\"{jedesWort[i]}\" is a number");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we define "number" as sequence of digits `'0'..'9'` with *word borders* we can use *regular expressions*, e.g. having

```
  string text = 
    "Hallo to the 1 that broke all my 12345 bones in my 2 legs, 2 hands and 20 fingers without touching my skull that has an IQ100 brain but 1big bone";
```

We can put

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  int count = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b[0-9]+\b").Count;
```

Here

```
 \b     - word border
 [0-9]+ - one or more digits in '0'..'9' range
 \b     - word border
```

Let's have a look at these numbers:

```
  var result = Regex
    .Matches(text, @"\b[0-9]+\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value);

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result); 

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1
12345
2
2
20
```

Comment: thank you for your time!! That's a good solution but the namespace and those methods are above my level. My prof. wants me to do this assignment using (using System) and the methods and using arrays, loops, branching statements, (string and char) -methods, functions, recursions... So if i did it your way it will not be accepted, because it's above my level haha

Answer (score 2):

This is a working solution for you case with comments explaining what each line does so you can understand and learn. there are many more that you can do to it to make it better and fool proof but for your current test case it's enough

```
string text = "Hallo to the 1 that broke all my 12345 bones in my 2 legs, 2 hands and 20 fingers without touching my skull that has an IQ100 brain but 1big bone";

// split the text by spaces so we end up with a collection of words
int count = text.Split(new[] { ' ' })
                // test all words in the collection
                .Where(word =>
                    // check if all element of the word matches a condition
                    // a string in composed of char so it will iterate on each char
                    word.All(letter =>  
                    // return true if the character is a digit
                    char.IsDigit(letter)))
                // return the count of all words we just filtered and kept if they were all made of digits
                .Count();
```

Comment: Franck thanks for your help and the explanation! The code works very good but I couldn't understand why hahaha, because i'm a beginner I just started to program in April and i'm not similar to `.Where`, `.All` and I want to ask if those `=>` are another way of writing an if-Statement?

Comment: @AhmedHa.K the `Where` and `All` are all part of `linq`. It's a query language that allow you to do many things on collections typically `IEnumarable` and/or `List<>`. `Linq` can be written in 2 ways. One is the query form (don't remember the exact name) but it look like `SQL` very much. The second (the one I used here) is called the `Lambda expression`. That last form is NOT limited to `Linq` and can be used in many other case. You would need to read on lambda expression.